# ¿Se puede insertar un separador en una cadena de números en javascript?

Tags: javascript, php

tengo el siguiente problema en javascript, tengo una variable que me entrega una cadena de números como los siguientes.

variable1 = 10152035;

lo que quiero hacer es que cada dos números se agregue una coma o cualquier carácter que los separe. quedando así

resultado =  10,15,20,35;

Pero no se como hacerlo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Intenta con esta función, donde utiliza el metodo **split** y una expresión regular para delimitar en donde sera asignado el separador, quedaría de esta forma:

```js
const numb=2132312212;

function separator(numb) {
    //PROCESAMOS LA CADENA
    var str = numb.toString().split(".");
    //EN LA EXPRESION INDICAMOS "2" CANTIDAD DE DIGITOS A SEPARAR Y AL FINAL "," QUE SERA EL DELIMITADOR
    str[0] = str[0].replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
    return str.join(".");
}

console.log(separator(numb))
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, igual me funciono, ya lleva un rato con este problema.

Answer (score 0):

ya lo resolví, utilice match() solo especifique los parámetros y listo.

Quedando algo así.

```js
let men1 = "10152035";
let arr = men1.match(/.{1,2}/g);
console.log(arr);
```

y me da como resultado 10,15,20,35

Por si a alguien le interesa o tiene el mismo problema que yo.